# Test if desired type or None is in list of objects

Tags: python, types

I want to check if every object in my list is of type str or is None

The following code fails

```
str or None in (type("hi"), type("ho"), type("hey"), None)
```

output:

```
str
```

My desired outcome should be True

and for the code:

```
str or None in (type("hi"), type("ho"), type("hey"), type(2))
```

The outcome should be False

Comment: Where is your object list?

Comment: `str or None in (type("hi"), type("ho"), type("hey"), type(2))` should actually be true (the first few types are still a string). However if you wanted to check if it contained *both* `str` and `None`, then I agree it should be false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this given that all the variables are given in a list like this.

```
lst = ['hi', 'ho', None]
ans = all(isinstance(i, (str, type(None))) for i in lst)
print(ans)
```

**Output**

```
True
```

Comment: `isinstance(i, (str, None))`

Comment: @Jab `None` is not a type. `isinstance(i, (str, type(None))) `

Comment: My mistake. Yes, either that or `isinstance(i, str) or i is None`

Comment: Missed out on the None type. Thanks for letting me know. Have made the edit accordingly.

Comment: `type(None)` to get the class of the None singleton

Answer (score 0):

Use `any` built-in function to check using a logical **or** condition, and similarly the `all` built-in function to check using a logical **and** condition.

```py
>>> result1 = all(typ in (str, None) for typ in (type("hi"), type("ho"), type("hey"), None))
>>> result1
True

>>> result2 = all(typ in (str, None) for typ in (type("hi"), type("ho"), type("hey"), type(2)))
>>> result2
False
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this: all(typ in (type("hi"), type("ho"), type("hey"), type(2), type(0.2), None) for typ in (str, None)) yields still True

Comment: @coderxXx I'm a bit confused - is that not as expected? with that you are checking if both `str` and `None` are in the types to check, which I would expect to be true.

Comment: i think i misformulated my question, i wanted to check if all objects in the list are either None or of type str in order to yield True

Comment: ah, I guess it's possible I might have misinterpreted the question as well.

Comment: @coderxXx to get the desired result in this case, looks like you just have to swap the order of statements in the `all` argument. I updated the answer, and looks like it should now give the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition to

```
types_tuple = (type("hi"), type("ho"), type("hey"), type(2))
print(str in types_tuple or None in types_tuple)
```

Output:

`True`